# Include inner nested objects when retrieving parent from database

Tags: entity-framework

There are lets say ParentObject which contains ChildObjects which contain GrandChildObjects (All of these are being stored in database), basically multiple nested classes, and the thing is when i retrieve ParentObject from dbContext I want it to be fully populated/refreshed, however ChildObjects are usually null, that is fixed by including `.Include(x => x.ChildObject)` , but how can i do this to deeper nested objects? So far this is what I'm using to retrieve all ParentObjects:

```
 // db -> DbContext
 return db.Parents
            .Include(x => x.Child1)
            .Include(x => x.Child2)
            .Include(x => x.Child3);
 // Now ChildObjects are refreshed, however objects inside them are not (GrandChildObjects)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply selecting the appropriate property. Either one:

```
.Include(x => x.Child1.GrandChild)
```

Or many:

```
.Include(x => x.Child1.Select(c => c.GrandChild))
```

Comment: Ohh, I don't know how I didn't come up with this, thanks!